# Python: how to combine elements in a 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

**I have this list**

```
[[0, 185], [0, 374], [0, 676], [0, 844], [1, 186], [1, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198], [3, 571], ...]
```

**i want it to be like this:**

```
[[0, 374,676,844], [1, 186, 440],[2, 202], [3, 198, 571], ...]
```

I tried this code:

```
for i in range(len(index)-1):
    if (index[i][0]==index[i+1][0]):
        index[i].append(index[i+1][1])
        del index[i+1]
        i=i-1
```

But it dosen't work

Comment: What is `index` - your code throws a NameError - please correct unless that is the problem you are asking about. `But it dosen't work` - what is wrong? How is it deficient. Please read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not advisable to delete items from the list you are iterating over. In Python it's more common (and easier) to generate a new list with comprehension.

You can make groups with [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and group by the the first item in the list. Then from those groups you can create the desired sub-groups by taking the key plus all the other second elements. Something like:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [[0, 185], [0, 374], [0, 676], [0, 844], [1, 186], [1, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198], [3, 571]]

[[k] + [i[1] for i in g] for k, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0])]
# [[0, 185, 374, 676, 844], [1, 186, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198, 571]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler solution:

```
lst = [[0, 185], [0, 374], [0, 676], [0, 844], [1, 186], [1, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198], [3, 571]]
newlst = []
curr_lst = []
max_index = 3

for x in range(max_index+1):
    
    curr_lst = [x]
    
    for y in lst:
        if y[0] == x:
            curr_lst.append(y[1])
    newlst.append(curr_lst)
    
print(newlst)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 185, 374, 676, 844], [1, 186, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198, 571]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way to implement. Just make sure before using the function you have sorted list by first index of sublist.

```
a = [[0, 185], [0, 374], [0, 676], [0, 844], [1, 186], [1, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198], [3, 571]]
    
    n = len(a)
    x = 0
    res = []
    r = [0]
    for i in a:
        if i[0] == x:
            r.append(i[1])
        else:
            x += 1
            res.append(r)
            r = [x, i[1]]
    res.append(r)
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use collections OrderedDict

```
 from collections import OrderedDict

l = [[0, 185], [0, 374], [0, 676], [0, 844], [1, 186], [1, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198], [3, 571]]
d = OrderedDict()
for inner in l:
    if inner[0] in d:
        d[inner[0]].append(inner[1])
    else:
        d[inner[0]] = [inner[1]]

print(d.values())
```

Comment: It also preserves the order

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries to collect the numbers from index 1 from input list.

```py
a=[[0, 185], [0, 374], [0, 676], [0, 844], [1, 186], [1, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198], [3, 571]]
b={}

[b[i[0]].append(i[1]) if i[0] in b else b.update({i[0]:[i[0],i[1]]}) for i in a]
b=list(b.values())

print(b)
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 185, 374, 676, 844], [1, 186, 440], [2, 202], [3, 198, 571]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without importing you can do in the following way -

```
new_dict = {}
result = []

for item in nest:
    if item[0] in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[item[0]].append(item[1])
    else:
        new_dict[item[0]] = [item[1]]

for key, value in new_dict.items():
    result.append([key] + value)
```